# Regex to handle '/' trim in URL

Tags: regex

I am using the following rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*) search.php?letter=$1&num=$2 [NC,L]`

It works fine when loading  "/search/a/1" in the browser, meaning that when debugging with PHP the values of the vars are:   `$letter='a'` and `$num=1` .

However, when loading "/search/a/1/" (with ' / ' at the end), the values of the vars are:
`$letters='a/1'` and `$num=NULL` .

What regex should I use to make both "/search/a/1" and "/search/a/1/" result in the same way?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*) search.php?letter=$1&num=$2 [NC,L]
```

This makes sure the groups `$1` and `$2` never contain a slash. The regex allows martial matching (no `$` at the end), so it will ignore further tokens: `/search/a/1/blah/blah` should work as expected.

To allow only a single slash at the end, and nothing more (make sure you don't have `.*` in other rules, of course):

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ search.php?letter=$1&num=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can prevent URLs like "/search/a/1/blah/blah" from working, and only allow "/search/a/1/" and "/search/a/1"?

Answer (score 1):

You're matching any character `.`, but want to match any character but a slash `[^/]`, so:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*) search.php?letter=$1&num=$2 [NC,L]
```